# Collapsing a PANDAs dataframe into a single column of all items and their occurances

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame consisting of a mixture of NaN's and strings e.g

```
data = {'String1':['NaN', 'tree', 'car', 'tree'],
        'String2':['cat','dog','car','tree'],
        'String3':['fish','tree','NaN','tree']}
ddf = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to

1:count the total number of items and put in a new data frame e.g

```
      NaN=2
      tree=5
      car=2
      fish=1
      cat=1
      dog=1
```

2:Count the total number of items when compared to a separate longer list (column of a another data frame, e.g

```
df['compare'] =
      NaN
      tree
      car
      fish
      cat
      dog
      rabbit
      Pear
      Orange
      snow
      rain
```

Thanks
Jason

Comment: roughly: df -> stack -> groupby -> count

Comment: What do you want to compare with df['compare'], or in other words what does df['compare'] contains?

Comment: Hello, df contains the items:            NaN
      tree
      car
      fish
      cat
      dog
      rabbit
      Pear
      Orange
      snow
      rain

Comment: Just to add.  The items in df['compare'] are my master list.  The items in my dataframe ddf are a sublist (or weekly list).  I want to populate in my master list (in a 2nd column), the number of occurances of each item in the first observed in the "weekly" dataframe ddf. (and then plot a bar chart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question:

```
from collections import Counter

data = {
    "String1": ["NaN", "tree", "car", "tree"],
    "String2": ["cat", "dog", "car", "tree"],
    "String3": ["fish", "tree", "NaN", "tree"],
}
ddf = pd.DataFrame(data)

a = Counter(ddf.stack().tolist())

df_result = pd.DataFrame(dict(a), index=['Count']).T

df = pd.DataFrame({'vals':['NaN', 'tree', 'car', 'fish', 'cat', 'dog', 'rabbit', 'Pear', 'Orange', 'snow', 'rain']})

df_counts = df.vals.map(df_result.to_dict()['Count'])
```

THis should do :)

Comment: Thankyou, any ideas how to count the occurances of strings in a dataframe df2 compared to df1. This was my attempt    df1['Netcount']=df1[0].map(df2[0].value_counts())

Comment: Please have a look.

Comment: I had an error:     a ----> 4 a = Counter(ddf.stack().tolist())

NameError: name 'Counter' is not defined

Comment: My bad, it has to be imported. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for count of items over all data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'String1':['NaN', 'tree', 'car', 'tree'],
        'String2':['cat','dog','car','tree'],
        'String3':['fish','tree','NaN','tree']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def get_counts(df: pd.DataFrame) -> dict:
    res = {}
    for col in df.columns:
        vc = df[col].value_counts().to_dict()
        for k,v in vc.items():
            if k in res:
                res[k] += v
            else:
                res[k] = v
    return res

counts = get_counts(df)
```

**Output**

```
>>> print(counts)
{'tree': 5, 'car': 2, 'NaN': 2, 'cat': 1, 'dog': 1, 'fish': 1}
```