# Is it possible to use Pandas groupby function with non-disjoint groups?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to extend a python program. Currently, it uses groupby to do some segmentation work.

The extension will allow rows to be in multiple groups. I'm not sure if groupby allows this, or how to simulate it. Or, if I just have to re-implement all of the functionality myself...

I don't have a really good example, because I'm unsure how I would represent it..

Below are three POSSIBLE representations of the data. Any would be fine, or others. I just need them to be able to give an example, and I don't want to limit the answers to one specific data format.

Version1 There is one 'grp' column, and it can have multiple values in it (comma separated here, but could be anything):

```
In [9]: v1                                                                                              
Out[9]: 
  name  value   grp
0    a     34     x
1    b     98   x,y
2    c      8     y
3    d      3     z
```

Version2 each possible values of the group has a 1/0 column:

```
In [14]: v2                                                                                             
Out[14]: 
  name  value  x  y  z
0    a     34  1  0  0
1    b     98  1  1  0
2    c      8  0  1  0
3    d      3  0  0  1
```

Version3 there are 3 grp columns, each with one or zero values, allowing for each row to be in up to three groups:

```
In [20]: v3                                                                                             
Out[20]: 
  name  value grp1 grp2 grp3
0    a     34    x          
1    b     98    x    y     
2    c      8    y          
3    d      3    z
```

Other implementations would also be fine, but I wanted to have some possible examples.

The output I want is, for example, imagine that there was a MULTIgroupby function that groups by a comma separated column and allows a single row to be in multiple groups:

```
v1.MULTIgroupby('grp').count()
```

to give:

```
grp   count
x     2
y     2
z     1
```

So, even though there are only 4 rows, the counts add up to 5. This is correct, and what I want.  count() is just one example. I want to be able to do mean, and median, and the ether groupby agg functions.

If this means I need to re-implement those by hand, then so be it. but I'd rather not if not necessary...

ETA: Adding more complicated examples:

Adding an additional value column:

```
In [27]: v1                                                                                             
Out[27]: 
  name  value   grp  value2
0    a     34     x      45
1    b     98  x, y       9
2    c      8     y     345
3    d      3     z       2

In [28]: v2                                                                                             
Out[28]: 
  name  value  x  y  z  value2
0    a     34  1  0  0      45
1    b     98  1  1  0       9
2    c      8  0  1  0     345
3    d      3  0  0  1       2

In [29]: v3                                                                                             
Out[29]: 
  name  value grp1 grp2 grp3  value2
0    a     34    x                45
1    b     98    x    y            9
2    c      8    y               345
3    d      3    z                 2
```

with groupby, I can do:

```
v3.groupby('grp1').mean()
```

I will get the mean for value and value2 by x, y, and z.

```
      value  value2
grp1               
x        66      27
y         8     345
z         3       2
```

I want:

```
      value  value2
grp               
x        66      27
y         53     177
z         3       2
```

And yes, I can calculate this myself with looping over all of the columns that I care about, and then looping over all of the grp columns in version2, for example, and filtering, and then running the mean() function. But the beauty of groupby is that I don't NEED to... I'm hoping to avoid this...

The fact that it's so hard for me to express this probably means that this is a sufficiently rare occasion that there isn't a simple way to do this...

Let me reiterate (at least I think I said it up there somewhere): I can figure out how to do this manually. That's not the question. The question is "Do I NEED to do this manually?" I didn't when grp only had one thing per row, I could use groupby. Do I now need to manually do everything myself? If the answer to that is "yes", then I'll get on that, but I'd rather not waste my time implementing multiply nested loops (I have multiple value columns, multiple grp columns and multiple values in the grp) if I don't have to...

I've added 2 Answers below, in case there is no easy groupby solution...

Comment: What do you exactly try to illuistrate with your versions? Are these all the possible versions which your data can have or are you trying to explain something else?

Comment: What you're asking is not clear at all, please make your question clearer or it will be closed since it's quite hard to make any sense out of it

Comment: The three v# examples are three different possible implementations how the same data could look.

Comment: @yatu Can you ask a more specific question? I'm not sure what is unclear. I have data that groupby doesn't quite work for, and I want to figure out how to make it work for me.

Comment: v2 would be easy for the output you expected: `v2[['x','y','z']].sum()`?

Comment: From your desired output, it seems like Version2, the dummy version, is the obvious choice. All of the others would require you to go through that version at some point. Once you have the dummies it's a simple sum.

Comment: This question is intuitively answered in this post (with your version3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271102/collapsing-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-single-column-of-all-items-and-their-occura/58271269#58271269

Comment: @Devrim Ok, so this basically means that I need to re-implement all other functions I want myself... I'm hoping to avoid that, because without this, groupby is so nice...

Comment: I see, what about summing 0/1 s as @Quang Hoang suggested ?

Comment: @Devrim That only gets me count. It doesn't get me median/mean, stddev, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this on Version 2 of the data.

```
cols=['x','y','z']
df[cols].sum()
df[cols].mean()
df[cols].std()
df[cols].var()
```

so on & so forth.

**Output**

for `df[cols].sum()`

```
x    2
y    2
z    1
```

for `df[cols].mean()`

```
x    0.50
y    0.50
z    0.25
```

**Update**

You can use the code below to get the sum/mean etc for each of x,y & z

```
for col in cols:
    print(col,df[df[col]==1]['value'].sum())
```

**Output**

```
x 132
y 106
z 3
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific. I want mean and median, etc of the val column for the rows that have 1 for 'x'... So, I can do tmp = df[df['x']==1]['val'].mean() probably. But that means re-writing everything...

Comment: Yeah, but then I have to do that for each value column (of which there are many) and each group. That seems error prone. I'd rather not have to do that it's avoidable...

Answer (score 0):

FOR EXAMPLE: 
If I were to have to solve this myself, I could use v2 above with:

```
In [55]: means = pd.DataFrame(columns=['grp', 'value', 'value2'])                                       

In [56]: for grp in grps: 
    ...:     m = v2.groupby(grp).mean() 
    ...:     m = m[['value', 'value2']] 
    ...:     m['grp'] = grp 
    ...:     means = means.append(m.loc[1])
```

Which at least gets rid of the loop by columns...

I'm HOPING that there is a solution that doesn't involve this...

Answer (score 0):

Another option (I guess people can vote? if they care?)  is to just add additional rows, in v1, so:

```
In [85]: v11                                                                                            
Out[85]: 
  name  value   grp  value2
0    a     34     x      45
1    b     98  x, y       9
2    c      8     y     345
3    d      3     z       2
4   b1     98     x       9
5   b2     98     y       9
```

THEN I do the normal groupby('grp') and I ignore the 'x,y' group...

```
Out[86]: 
      value  value2
grp                
x        66      27
x, y     98       9
y        53     177
z         3       2
```

And make sure I'm doing all of this on a copy so that I don't screw up the original data...